# Deserialization of Map<String,Object> without Class definition

Tags: java, serialization, ejb

**Can a remote EJB deserialize a Map object without a jar file containing the class files associated with the Objects that are stored in the Map?**

Let's say we have created the following Java class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class MyCustomObject implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3100182702835154967L;

    private String myString;
    private int myInt;

    public String getMyString()
    {
        return myString;
    }

    public void setMyString(String myString) 
    {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    public int getMyInt()
    {
        return myInt;
    }

    public void setMyInt(int myInt)
    {
        this.myInt = myInt;
    }
}
```

We place an instance of this class in a Map:

```
Map<String, Object> mapOfObjects = new HashMap<String, Object>();       
MyCustomObject customObject = new MyCustomObject();
customObject.setMyInt(3);
customObject.setMyString("Hello");
mapOfObjects.put("MyCustomObjectKey", customObject);
```

If I now pass this Map object to a remote EJB, assuming the remote EJB does not have a reference to the MyCustomObject class, will an exception be thrown during the deserialization process?

I understand that if I want to retrieve the custom object from the Map I would have to have a reference to the MyCustomObject class

```
public class RemoteEJB()
{
    public void remoteMethod(Map<String,Object> mapOfObjects)
    {
        MyCustomObject customObject =  (MyCustomObject)mapOfObjects.get("MyCustomObjectKey"); //java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - Won't compile
    }
}
```

The question is: Assuming I don't want to pull the object out of the Map, would the remoteMethod invocation take place on the remote EJB or would an exception be thrown?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: I want to understand the reason behind the outcome, not just the outcome itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because HashMap's deserialization will immediately require the secondary object to be deserialized, which will fail.  If you need to support this use-case, you could write a custom Map that performs an inner serialization step (that is, writeObject creates a new ObjectOutputStream to write the inner objects), and then perform on-demand deserialization (that is, get() creates a new ObjectInputStream to read the inner objects).